# My app disappeared from Google Play with Marshmallow update on my device

Tags: android, google-play

When my personal phone upgraded to Marshmallow (6.0.1), my app became no longer visible in Google Play.

The manifest has:

1. Minimum SDK: 10
2. Target SDK: 22
3. No maximum SDK

I tried uploading a test app with everything the same except with Target SDK = 24, and it did show up in Google Play.

While I could upgrade the app for Marshmallow, I would rather not have to.

What is going on and can I do anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

Im might be wrong, however, I believe you have to update your manifest and upload the apk again.

Basically, your current manifest is targeting devices with android version from 10 to 22.

You have to change your manifest and set target SDK to 23.

This is expected since your app may not work well in android MM.

You are responsible to update the manifest, test and only after that, upload the new version to Google Play store.

Comment: This is not consistent with past Play Store practice. The target SDK is not normally used to limit visibility. There is a "maximum" SDK that can be used for that.

Is MM different in that regard? The documentation on the permissions changes strongly suggests that having a target of 22 or less will work on MM.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel really dumb, and not to happy with the Play Store search algorithm!

The app **is** *still* visible. But, even though I searched for it by the starting two words of its name, it was so far down in the play listings that I didn't see it. This is an app with over 10,000 installs and a rating around 4.5 and current sales.

So, if you don't see you app in the play store on a device, scroll all the way through the category, or put in the entire name.